# Calling a function when document is ready?

Tags: jquery

When my document is ready I do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ReferenceID').change(function () { reLoad(); });
});
```

However I would also like to trigger an execution of the reLoad() function when the document
becomes ready.

How can I call that function?

Inside reLoad() I would like to have something to put up a message showing the word "Loading". Something like jQgrid when it loads data. Is that easy to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, then all you need to do is call the function in the `ready` event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    reLoad(); //Calls reLoad
    $('#ReferenceID').change(function () { reLoad(); });
});
```

Note that if you don't need to do anything else in the `change` event handler, and you don't need to pass any arguments to `reLoad`, you could just pass a reference to `reLoad` to the `change` method:

```
$('#ReferenceID').change(reLoad);
```

Answer (score 2):

simply :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 reLoad();
    $('#ReferenceID').change(function () { reLoad(); });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you can bind reLoad directly to the Change event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ReferenceID').change(reLoad);
});
```

And to call it, either trigger change, or call it directly

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#ReferenceID').change(reLoad);
   $('#ReferenceID').trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    reLoad();
    $('#ReferenceID').change(function () { reLoad(); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you have your answer but you could also do this:

```
$(document).ready(reLoad);
```

This uses your function (reLoad) as the document ready event handler.